# JDBC connection Exception

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I am getting the exception ORA-12504, TNS:listener was not given the SID in CONNECT_DATA
Could you please help me on this what went wrong? 
**tnsnames.ora**

```
SUNRISEDB =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVICE_NAME = SUNRISEDB)
    )
  )
```

**listener.ora**

```
LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = pacdcinfoddpodbc.cable.comcast.com)(PORT = 1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )
```

ADR_BASE_LISTENER = C:\app\kkumar003c

and my java code is

```
try {
                Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
                 dbConn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@147.191.10.119:1521","KIRANDB","KIRANDB"); 
                System.out.println();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        System.out.println("db connection=="+dbConn);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this line -

```
dbConn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@147.191.10.119:1521","KIRANDB","KIRANDB");
```

to

```
dbConn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@147.191.10.119:1521:**SUNRISEDB**","KIRANDB","KIRANDB");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need your schema name in the place of *NAME*.

```
dbConn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@147.191.10.119:1521:NAME","KIRANDB","KIRANDB");
```